# how to check if there is a notification just like the one im creating

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

the app i'm doing have to schedule an notifications if the user choose to 
every time the user close the app the must must check and make the notification based on the user choice 
the problem is if the user choose to have notification every time he close the app my code will put new notification for the same the thing so when the notification is fired there will be many notification instead of just one 
i need to know if i can check if there is scheduled notification just like the one that i'm trying to make to avoid duplication and have one notification only
here is my code:

```
private void createScheduledNotification(long dateop,int days,String vaa,String naa)
    {
        Calendar calendars = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendars.setTimeInMillis(dateop);
        if(days<30){
            calendars.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, days *24);
            }
        else{
            calendars.add(Calendar.MONTH, days/30);
            }
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeReceiver.class); 
        intent.putExtra("username", naa);
        intent.putExtra("vaccine", vaa);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendars.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

     }
```